# Facebook javascript SDK - Not able to post score

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Javascript SDK to post score to FB but it is giving me error ({error:{message:"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", type:"OAuthException", code:15}}) :

I am using accessToken coming from following:

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
        // app, and response.authResponse supplies
        // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
        // request, and the time the access token 
        // and signed request each expire
        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
```

The function i am using to post score is following:

```
    FB.api("uid/scores", 'post', {score: scoredata, access_token: accessToken },
            function(response) 
        {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              console.error(response);
           } else {
              console.log(response);
           }
        });
```

Can anyone please give idea since fb is missing docs for JAvascript specially.

Jacob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of fact that scores should be posted as application not as users.

What you trying to do should be done using [Application `access_token`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) and from server-side (not JavaScript in browser) so your application secret will not be revealed.

Comment: No it's not because of that .

Answer (score 0):

For posting scores on Facebook Games using user access token you do not need to pass Access Token in this call anymore, it would work too, but not necessary .
The error on your code is that FB.api must be called with / after the ' before me, and i think you need use ME instead of user id .

```
 FB.api('/me/scores/', 'post', { scores: score }, function(response) {
    if( response.error ) {
      console.error('Failed',response);
    } else {
      console.log('Posted', response);
               }    
  });
```

You need publish_actions permission for posting and **this will always set up the new score value**, only works for High Score if you code .. to Get user scores, using user_game_activities and use JavaScript to compare values, then post if new value is bigger .

You can also set high scores using the App Token, using a very different call .
I had been using this to save the user credits in a slot machine game, and i found that can save and get the scores many times to keep it updated and saved between two or more game sessions .
I also have the realtime Facebook Game Scores Leaderboard, and it also works without app access token, because its relacional, and only displays your friends scores .

Thats how i'm doing it, and i love it, Facebook Platform is awesome .

[image: Realtime Facebook Game Scores Leaderboard]